# How to use leaflet-measure-path with GeoJSON Linestring?

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geojson, linestring

I am trying to use the "leaflet-measure-path" plugin for leaflet to print the segment length of some geojson linestrings.

I am using the "Leaflet Ajax" plugin to load the GeoJSON files into my map and am then applying different markers and different line styles depending on the properties of the "Features"

I am running into an issue `"Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).on(...).showMeasurements is not a function"` even though I have definitely included the plugin. i am thinking it may not be compatible with linestrings? if it is not, what are my options?

here is the code that retrieves the geojson and proccesses it.

```
function filterLines(url2) {
    var lineLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX(url2, {
        pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
            if (feature.properties.type == 'Marker') {
                return L.marker(latlng, {icon: icon[feature.properties.icon]});
            } else {
                return L.marker(latlng, {icon: lineMarker});
            }

            L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);
        }, style: myStyle, onEachFeature: lineDirection
    }).on('click', lineOnClick).showMeasurements().addTo(linesGroup);
}

function lineOnClick(e){
    if (e.layer.feature.geometry.type == 'Point' && e.layer.feature.properties.type != 'Marker') {
        var point = e.layer.feature.properties.id;
        var pointLatLng = e.latlng;
        popup.setContent("<b>Type: </b>" + e.layer.feature.properties.lineType + "<br><a href='#' onclick=\"loadDoc('line?m=lineMarkerForm&id=" + e.layer.feature.properties.lineLatLngID + "&type=" + e.layer.feature.properties.lineTypeID + "', 'onscreenForm', 'osfBody');\"><img src='<?php $db->baseurl ?>img/map/plus.png'></a><br><b>Notes: </b>" + e.layer.feature.properties.notes + "<br><a href='#' onclick=\"loadDoc('line?m=lineForm&id=" + e.layer.feature.properties.lineID + "', 'onscreenForm', 'osfBody');\"><img src='<?php $db->baseurl ?>img/map/edit.png'></a><a href='#' onclick='forkLineFunc(" + point + ", " + pointLatLng.lat + ", " + pointLatLng.lng + ")'><img src='<?php $db->baseurl; ?>img/fork.png'></a>");
        window.popup.setLatLng(e.latlng);
        window.popup.openOn(map);
    } else if(e.layer.feature.geometry.type == 'Point' && e.layer.feature.properties.type == 'Marker'){
        var point = e.layer.feature.properties.id;
        var pointLatLng = e.latlng;
        popup.setContent("<b>ID: </b>"+e.layer.feature.properties.id+"<br><b>Type: </b>" + e.layer.feature.properties.markerType + "<br><b>Notes: </b>" + e.layer.feature.properties.notes + "<br><a href='#' onclick=\"loadDoc('line?m=lineMarkerForm&id=" + e.layer.feature.properties.id + "&type=" + e.layer.feature.properties.lineTypeID + "', 'onscreenForm', 'osfBody');\"><img src='<?php $db->baseurl ?>img/map/edit.png'></a><a href='#' onclick='forkLineFunc(" + point + ", " + pointLatLng.lat + ", " + pointLatLng.lng + ")'><img src='<?php $db->baseurl; ?>img/fork.png'></a>");
        window.popup.setLatLng(e.latlng);
        window.popup.openOn(map);
    } else if (e.layer.feature.geometry.type == 'LineString') {
        popup.setContent("<b>Type: </b>"+e.layer.feature.properties.lineType+"<br><b>Notes: </b>"+e.layer.feature.properties.notes+"<br><b>Approx Length: </b>"+e.layer.feature.properties.totalDistance.toFixed(1)+"m");
        window.popup.setLatLng(e.latlng);
        window.popup.openOn(map);
    }
}
function lineDirection(feature, layer) {
    var layerType = layer.feature.geometry.type;
    if (layerType == 'Point'){
    } else if (layerType == 'LineString') {
        if(feature.properties.direction == 'Normal') {
            L.polylineDecorator(layer, {
                patterns: [
                    {
                        offset: 10,
                        repeat: 40,
                        symbol: L.Symbol.arrowHead({
                            pixelSize: 12,
                            pathOptions: {fillOpacity: 1, weight: 0, color: lineColour}
                        })
                    }
                ]
            }).addTo(linesGroup);
        }
        if(feature.properties.direction == 'Reversed'){
                L.polylineDecorator(layer, {
                    patterns: [
                        {offset: 10, repeat: 40, symbol: L.Symbol.reverseArrow({pixelSize: 12, pathOptions: {fillOpacity: 1, weight: 0, color: lineColour}})}
                    ]
                }).addTo(linesGroup);
        }
    } else {
        // do something else, not needed yet...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated on the [Leaflet Measure Path plugin API doc](https://github.com/ProminentEdge/leaflet-measure-path#api), the new methods (like `showMeasurements`) are added to Leaflet's `L.Polyline`, `L.Polygon` and `L.Circle` classes, therefore not on `L.GeoJSON` class, like the instance created by `L.GeoJSON.AJAX` plugin.

However, you can simply use the Layer Group method [`eachLayer`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup-eachlayer) to loop through all child layers of your GeoJSON group, perform your geometry type detection and call `showMeasurements()` when relevant:

```js
lineLayer.eachLayer(function (layer) {
  if (layer.feature.geometry.type === 'LineString') {
    layer.showMeasurements(); // Must be called once already added to map.
  }
});
```

BTW, you can also directly bind popups to your layers, instead of dynamically creating them when a user clicks on a layer, using the [`bindPopup`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layer-bindpopup) method. You can do so either during the group creation (using [`onEachFeature`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson-oneachfeature) option of your `L.GeoJSON.AJAX` constructor, like you have done with `pointToLayer` and `style`), or later on using the `eachLayer` method like above.

```js
L.geoJSON(geoJSONdata, {
  onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
    // bindPopup during creation directly.
    layer.bindPopup('Type: ' + feature.geometry.type + '<br />Notes: ' + feature.properties.notes);
  }
})
```

Live example: https://plnkr.co/edit/7wL8QHNuXEW1qMvMVjY5?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the help, i am having trouble getting it to work. its now no longer erroring but just not showing the measurements. have not yet had a chance to look at your tip for the popups but will do.

Comment: Feel free to open a new question again, with relevant details and code to reproduce your issue.